# PHP $_FILES are empty while the file is sent to server

Tags: php, angularjs, file, upload

I want to use https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/ for file uploading. I'm trying to catch the uploaded file using the `$_FILES` global array. While the content of file is sent to the server, it seems PHP could not catch uploaded file meta-data (file name etc). So $_FILES is empty. By the way, it's strange that I should set both file and data properties to `file`

```
    $scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files != null && files[0]) {
            var file = files[0];
            console.log(file);

            file.upload = Upload.http({
                url: 'rest/file/',
                data:file,
                fileName:'test',
                file: file
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                file.result = response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });

            file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    }
```

HTML markup:

```
           <p>
                <label for="background">Background</label>
                <input ngf-select ngf-change="upload($files)" accept="image/*"
                       ng-model="form.background"
                       name="background" type="file"/>
                <img ng-show="form.background[0] != null" ngf-thumbnail="form.background[0]" class="thumb"/>
                        <span class="meter" ng-show="form.background[0].progress >= 0">
                                <span style="width:{{form.background[0].progress}}%"
                                      ng-bind="form.background[0].progress + '%'"
                                      class="ng-binding">
                                </span>
                        </span>

            </p>
```

Comment: hi @phpst, did you find a fix for this?

Comment: I don't remember. I moved to https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

check file_uploads = On, post_max_size, and upload_max_file_size in php.ini. Also try increase memory_limit in php.ini